# SQL Server : trigger only affecting 1 row

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a procedure which takes data from an external JSON and parses it into a table, which works perfectly. Now I am trying to make a trigger so that, whenever a dataset is added, the trigger separates the data into the appropriate tables and columns.

```
CREATE TRIGGER main.afterParsing 
ON main.jsontable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    --Country Variables
    DECLARE @CountryCountry NVARCHAR(50)

    --Person Variables
    DECLARE @PersonName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonSurname NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonEmail NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonAge NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonCountry NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonRegistered NVARCHAR(50)

    --Get Country
    SELECT @CountryCountry = jsontable.country FROM inserted jsontable;

    --Insert Country
    INSERT INTO country(countryName)
        SELECT @CountryCountry
        WHERE @CountryCountry NOT IN (Select CountryName FROM Country)
END;
```

This is the trigger, but for some reason it is only updating a single row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CountryCountry is holding single country or multiple countries ?

Comment: It should be holding a single one. It is giving me that single country, but how do I make it go from row to row in the trigger? as it is only taking the country of row 1

Comment: triggers should be batch aware

Comment: Are you doing bulk insert in your source table?

Comment: Yes I am getting the JSON file's information using BulkColumn

Comment: That's the reason check the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

By default bulk, statement do not execute triggers. However, you can enable triggers by using FIRE_TRIGGERS qualifiers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.105).aspx 
and below is updated code for your trigger.

```
GO

CREATE TRIGGER main.afterParsing ON main.jsontable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    --Country Variables
    DECLARE @CountryCountry NVARCHAR(50)

    --Person Variables
    DECLARE @PersonName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonSurname NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonEmail NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonAge NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonCountry NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonRegistered NVARCHAR(50)

    --Get Country
    SELECT @CountryCountry = jsontable.country FROM inserted jsontable;

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select CountryName FROM Country WHERE CountryName=@CountryCountry)
    BEGIN
    --Insert Country
    INSERT INTO country(countryName)
    VALUES (@CountryCountry)
   END 

END;

GO
```

Comment: It is still only affecting 1 row