# SQL - Batch Insert Into No Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger which is triggered when data is inserted into a table. The data that is inserted into said table is taken from JSON, which works properly. My issue is that, I want to separate the data from this table into separate tables. I want to take the countries and store them in their own table. It is working to take the data but it is inserting duplicate data. How do I eliminate the duplicates from being stored?

```
CREATE TRIGGER main.afterParsing 
ON main.jsontable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    --Rows
    DECLARE @Count INT;
    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT;

    --Person Variables
    DECLARE @PersonName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonSurname NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonEmail NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonAge NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonCountry NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PersonRegistered NVARCHAR(50)

    --Insert Country
    INSERT INTO country(countryName)
        SELECT jsontable.country
        FROM jsontable
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT countryName 
                           FROM country 
                           WHERE country.countryName = jsontable.country)) 
          AND (jsontable.country IS NOT NULL)

    --Get Person

    --Insert Person

END;
```

Comment: Based on the syntax, I surmise that this is SQL Server, but you should accurately tag your own questions.  You should investigate `merge`.

Comment: I don't see any issue so far in the query the only chance is replaced where clause with following way  S--Get Country
    SELECT @CountryCountry = jsontable.country FROM inserted jsontable;

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select CountryName FROM Country WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(CountryName))=LTRIM(RTRIM(@CountryCountry)))
    BEGIN
    --Insert Country
    INSERT INTO country(countryName)
    VALUES (@CountryCountry)
   END

Comment: What is the meaning of all the variable declarations, when none of those variables are used? You don't reference `inserted` either. I'm confused by your statement here as it stands.

Comment: The declarations will be used further on in the statement, but I want to fix the first part before continuing. Also why do I need to refernce inserted?

Comment: refer my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539054/sql-server-trigger-only-affecting-1-row/50539126#50539126

Comment: Generally, a trigger that occurs `AFTER INSERT` would be expected to reference those rows, otherwise I have the question of "does it need to be a trigger?" Probably not if you're not referencing the affected rows.

Comment: Ah ok that is what im attempting to do. How can I refer to these rows?

Comment: The rows inserted are available in `inserted`.

Answer (score 1):

My little issue was solved by simply modifying the `SELECT` statement to `SELECT DISTINCT`.